# Regex replace commas within parentheses C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm having a hell of a time replacing commas only within parentheses for this string:

> select distinct  \n(''+rtrim(ent.custno)+' -
>   '+rtrim(ent.company)+'') as customer, ent.phone, 0 as
>   curr,\n\n(select SUM(billmast.balance) as balance from billmast where
>   billmast.billid = ent.entid and ent.cid = 'abis' and
>   billmast.balance<>0 and billmast.invdate>dateadd(day,-60, getdate())
>   and billmast.invdate0 and billmast.invdate>dateadd(day,-90, getdate())
>   and billmast.invdate0 and billmast.invdate>dateadd(day,-120, getdate())
>   and billmast.invdate0 and billmast.adddate

What I've tried:

```
        //// replaces nothing
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, ",*(?=[^(]*\\))", m => m.Value.Replace(",", ";"));

        //// adds semi-colon between each character inside parentheses
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, ",*(?=[^(]*\\))", ";");

        //// replaces nothing
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, ",(?=[^(]*\\))", ";");

        //// replaces nothing
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, ",(?=[^(]*\\))", m => m.Value.Replace(",", ";"));

        //// replaces nothing
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, @",(?=[^()]*\))", ";");

        //// replaces nothing
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, @",(?=[^()]*\))", m => m.Value.Replace(",", ";"));

        //// adds semi-colon between each character inside parentheses
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, ",*(?=[^()]*\\))", ";");

        // replaces all commas with semi-colon - not just ones in parentheses
        //cols = Regex.Replace(cols, ",(?![^(]*\\))", ";");
```

...among many other things.

```
,(?![^(]*\\)
```

seems to work in the demo below, but not in C#
https://regex101.com/r/mO1bZ5/1

Comment: You must escape the parentheses in a character group too: `[^\(]`.

Comment: Try [`@"(?<=\([^()]*),"`](http://goo.gl/anHLNG). If your parentheses are paired it should work.

Comment: Does this http://ideone.com/C72aRs work as expected?

Comment: If you need more help with this please consider dropping a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your parentheses are paired and can be nested (balanced), and you need to replace all commas inside those balanced parentheses, you can use a regex to match those substrings and replace the commas with a match evaluator:

```
cols = Regex.Replace(cols, @"\((?>[^()]|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)", m => m.Value.Replace(",", ";"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5IQoN3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your string contains nested parenthesis. Your pattern must take in account this fact and describe eventual nested parenthesis like in this example string: `(aaaaa,bbbbb(cccc(dddd)eeee)ffff)` to be sure that the closing parenthesis is the good one.

```
string pattern = @",(?=(?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*?(?(depth)(?!))\))";
cols = Regex.Replace(cols, pattern, ";");
```

Named captures (that captures nothing here) act like a counter.

Each time an opening parenthesis is encountered, the counter is incremented, and each time a closing parenthesis is encountered, the counter is decremented. At the end, the conditional `(?(depth)...)` checks the counter (named `depth` in the example) and if it is not null, it forces the pattern to fail with the *always failing assertion*: `(?!)` (literally: *not followed by nothing*).

details:

```
,
(?=
    (?>                 # open an atomic group: important because a simple 
                        # non-capturing group(?:[^()]+)* may cause a catastrophic
                        # backtracking if the end of the pattern doesn't succeed.

        [^()]+          # all that is not a parenthesis
      |
        \( (?<depth>)   # a opening parenthesis increments the counter
      |
        \) (?<-depth>)  # a closing parenthesis decrements the counter
    )*?                 # a non-greedy quantifier is used because the group must
                        # be repeated until the end of the pattern succeeds
                        # (it prevents the regex engine to match all the string
                        # and to give back characters until the pattern succeeds)

    (?(depth) (?!) )    # check the counter and forces to fail when not null
    \)
)
```

Comment: I think matching nested parentheses substrings and replacing a `,` inside them with `;` using a match evaluator would be more efficient. Don't you think?

Comment: @stribizhev: I think it depends of the string (how many parenthesis without commas, how many commas outside parenthesis, ...)