# Best way to replace a comma with a semicolon inside parenthesis of a string

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

Given the following string:

```
string foo = "Foo, Bar, Baz (A, B, C), Fiz, Bang (Fiz, Bang)";
```

And what I want  to change it to is

```
Foo, Bar, Baz (A; B; C), Fiz, Bang (Fiz; Bang)
```

ALTERNATIVELY, if I can somehow transform it into an array of strings in the following manner in List:

```
Foo
Bar
Baz (A, B, C)
Fiz
Bang (Fiz, Bang)
```

Right now I'm doing a pretty nasty method which has a custom foreach and doesn't feel clean or scalable. I feel like I'm doing this the hard way when there's a better way.

So I appeal to the hivemind for a better solution.

Edit:

```
        public static void StuntForEachNext<T>(this IList<T> collection, Action<T, T, bool> func)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                func(collection[i], collection[i + 1], i == collection.Count - 2);
            }
        }
```

```
internal class Stunt_Parsed
        {
            public string MainStuntName { get; set; }
            public int StuntCount { get; set; }

            public List<string> Assigned_Associated_Stunts { get; set; } = new List<string>();

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"Stunt: {MainStuntName} x{StuntCount} ({Assigned_Associated_Stunts.Count})";
            }

            public static List<Stunt_Parsed> ParseStunts(string stunts)
            {
                List<Stunt_Parsed> returnStunts = new List<Stunt_Parsed>();

                bool isInParen = false;
                Stunt_Parsed newStunt = new Stunt_Parsed();

                stunts.Split(',').StuntForEachNext((stunt, nextStunt, isNextLast) =>
                {
                    string parsed_stunt = stunt;

                    if (stunt.Contains('('))
                    {
                        isInParen = true;
                        // Combine this one and the next one
                        string assoc_stunt = stunt + "," + nextStunt;
                        // Parse the things inside of the parentheses
                        int p1 = assoc_stunt.IndexOf('('); // 16
                        int p2 = assoc_stunt.Length;
                        if (assoc_stunt.Contains(')'))
                        {
                            p2 = assoc_stunt.IndexOf(')');
                            isInParen = false;
                        }

                        string s2 = assoc_stunt.Substring(p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1); // "Aura shield, dynamic shield, myfoo
                        string assoc_stunt1 = string.Empty;
                        string assoc_stunt2 = string.Empty;

                        foreach (string x in s2.Split(','))
                        {
                            string newString = x.Trim();
                            newStunt.Assigned_Associated_Stunts.Add(newString);
                        }

                        parsed_stunt = (parsed_stunt.Substring(0, parsed_stunt.Length - (parsed_stunt.Length - parsed_stunt.IndexOf('(')))).Trim(); // Spell Focus x2
                    }
                    else if (nextStunt.Contains(')') || isInParen)
                    {
                        // Already parsed
                        // Do nothing.
                        string newString = nextStunt.Replace(",", "").Replace(")", "").Trim();
                        newStunt.Assigned_Associated_Stunts.Add(newString);
                        if (nextStunt.Contains(')'))
                        {
                            returnStunts.Add(newStunt);
                            isInParen = false;
                            newStunt = new Stunt_Parsed();
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (stunt.Contains(')'))
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    parsed_stunt = parsed_stunt.Trim();

                    if (parsed_stunt.ToLower().Contains(" x"))
                    {
                        int lastX = parsed_stunt.ToLower().LastIndexOf("x");
                        newStunt.StuntCount = int.Parse(parsed_stunt.Substring(lastX + 1, parsed_stunt.Length - lastX - 1));
                        newStunt.MainStuntName = parsed_stunt.Substring(0, lastX - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newStunt.StuntCount = 1;
                        newStunt.MainStuntName = parsed_stunt;
                    }

                    if (!isInParen)
                    {
                        returnStunts.Add(newStunt);
                        newStunt = new Stunt_Parsed();
                    }
                });

                return returnStunts;
            }
        }
```

This code is about to have to be re-written because I've been informed that the things in parenthesis may be more complicated than simply coma's, so I decided that, for the moment, I'll simply store them in a string.

However, I thought I might appeal to greater minds because otherwise I'll simply just do a `x += ", " nextStunt;` until the closed parenthesis

Comment: You may use `Regex` for that. However, please share your current code

Comment: You should check out this question/answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618415/regex-replace-commas-within-parentheses-c-sharp

Comment: Using `Regex` is definitely the best way

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the regex way.

Comment: Regex.Replace(input, @"\((?>[^()]|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)", m => m.Value.Replace(",", ";")); -- was the answer from Thatsnotamuffin. Thanks everyone, I'll close the question. You rock!

Answer (score 2):

You can try *Finite State Machine* (FSM); it has `foreach` loop, which I hope is simple, not ugly one:

```
  private static string Transform(string value) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      return value;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

    int count = 0;

    foreach (char c in value) 
      if (c == ',') 
        sb.Append(count > 0 ? ';' : c);
      else {
        sb.Append(c);

        if (c == '(')
          count += 1;
        else if (c == ')')
          count -= 1;      
      }  

    return sb.ToString();  
  }
```

Then

```
  string result = Transform(foo);
```